# Why are methods considered the class attributes in Python?

Tags: object-oriented, python, conventions

I read in a book that both *methods* and *fields* are considered the *attributes* of a class in Python. However, recently I was told by a friend of mine that methods may **not** be considered the *attributes* of a class.

Then I decided to check this out again, and found this question mentioned on Wikipedia saying that this is a Python "tradition" to refer to methods as attributes, in contrast to other object-oriented programming languages.

So my question is: why are methods considered the class atributes along with the fields in Python in contrast to other languages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your friend was wrong. Methods *are* attributes.

Everything in Python is objects, really, with methods and functions and anything with a `__call__()` method being *callable* objects. They are all objects that respond to the `()` call expression syntax.

Attributes then, are objects found by attribute lookup on other objects. It doesn't matter to the attribute lookup mechanism that what is being looked up is a callable object or not.

You can observe this behaviour by looking up *just* the method, and not calling it:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x1023f5590>>
```

Here `f.bar` is an attribute lookup expression, the result is a method object.

Of course, your friend me be a little bit right too; what is really happening is that methods are special objects that wrap *functions*, keeping references to the underlying instance and original function, and are created on the fly by accessing the function as an attribute. But that may be complicating matters a little when you first start out trying to understand Python objects. If you are interested in how all that works, read the [Python Descriptor HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to see how attributes with special methods are treated differently on certain types of attribute access.

This all works because Python is a dynamic language; no type declarations are required. As far as the language is concerned, it doesn't matter if `Foo.bar` is a string, a dictionary, a generator, or a method. This is in contrast to compiled languages, where data is very separate from methods, and each field on an instance needs to be pinned down to a specific type beforehand. Methods generally are *not* objects, thus a separate concept from data.

Comment: That's a clear explanation. Thanks! But what about the other languages (like C++, for example)? Are there any difference between the _methods_ and _fields_ for the attribute lookup process in those languages?

Comment: Python is a dynamic language, and attributes do not need to be typed beforehand. With C++ on the other hand, the compiler nails everything down, so it makes much more sense to distinguish between data and methods. Methods are not objects in C++.

Comment: In Python 3 methods are even less special. There aren't any unbound methods any more. All functions are descriptors which create bound methods when looked up through the class (and as in Python 2, any custom callable class can add a three-line `__get__` to get the same behavior, though I've never seen anyone do this).

Comment: Yup, just didn't want to go into that much excruciating detail..